# How to sum items per year and type in an aggregated total - R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with number of new items of different created each year:

```
# Sample data
df = data.frame(n_new = c(1,    1,    2,    4,    5,    3),
                type = c("a",  "b",  "a",  "b",  "a",  "a"),
                year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005))
df
#   n_new type year
# 1     1    a 2000
# 2     1    b 2000
# 3     2    a 2001
# 4     4    b 2003
# 5     5    a 2004
# 6     3    a 2005
```

Since these items continue to exist the subsequent years, I'd like to aggregate them into a growing total number of existing items, for each type...

```
# Expected result
df$n_total = c(1, 1, 3, 5, 8, 11)
df
#   n_new type year n_total
# 1     1    a 2000       1
# 2     1    b 2000       1
# 3     2    a 2001       3
# 4     4    b 2003       5
# 5     5    a 2004       8
# 6     3    a 2005      11
```

To do this, I tried to sum each value (per type) with the previous year's value...

```
df$n_total[df$type = "a"] <- df$n_new[df$type = "a"] + 
                             df$n_new[df$type = "a" & df$year - 1] 
# It obviously doesn't work ;-)
```

It seems pretty obvious, and yet, I can't find how to reference `year-1`... I could do it with a `for` loop, but I am sure `R` has some better solution. I just can't put my finger on it!

Comment: Check out: ?cumsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the dplyr `group_by` function plus `mutate` and  `cumsum`, as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(n_new = c(1,    1,    2,    4,    5,    3),
                type = c("a",  "b",  "a",  "b",  "a",  "a"),
                year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005))

df$n_total<-cumsum(df$n_new)


df %>%group_by(type) %>%  mutate(ntotalbytype = cumsum(n_new))
```

Results in:

```
  n_new   type  year ntotalbytype
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1      a  2000            1
2     1      b  2000            1
3     2      a  2001            3
4     4      b  2003            5
5     5      a  2004            8
6     3      a  2005           11
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I only realized afterwards that I couldn't use `cumsum()` to only sum the counts for each type (I thought it would be straightforward, but I don't find the solution). So I changed a little bit my question with this additional difficulty.

Comment: No problem see the edits to the answer above.